# IntelliJ idea resolving python venv depenency

Tags: python, intellij-idea

In my project I have

```
import datetime as dt
```

Which can not be resolved in IntelliJ idea..

I do have requirements.in file

> python -m piptools compile --upgrade sergii-requirements.in

and generated requirements.txt with **datetime** defined there

> python -m piptools sync requirements.txt

These dependencies are set in my activated virtual environment (`venv` folder)

yet, I am not sure how to make IntelliJ idea aware of that venv.
and my dependencies and make it resolved ? (not that intuitive.. for java dev..)

**UPDATE**:
I did try it in `PyCharm`, it did work as soon as I set:

Project SKD to `/home/user/projects/my-project/venv/bin/python3.9` - it did resolve everything.

Same thing did not & have not yet worked in IntellJ Idea.. (2021.1)

Update 2:

BUT: how do I know that resolved depenency is from my venv. Seems it is not.

Comment: Did you check your Project Settings in PyCharm / IntelliJ? It should have the appriopriate interpreter (the one from your venv) set as the interpreter for your project.

Comment: @rv.kvetch please don't provide an opinion like that on SO - that's not what the site is for. OP is asking how to get things to work with IntelliJ, not asking for advice on better environments (and if they were, the question would get nixed). As far as I know, the resolution is the same anyway.

Comment: i have a license for intelliJ idea (Ultimate). i guess if I use PyCharm it would require another lisence. But I will try.

Comment: Quick tip (at the risk of getting this question closed, again not my intention), but in Pycharm you can change interpreter easily using bottom right icon which shows your Python version also.

Comment: To check if resolved dependency is coming from your venv, you can `Ctrl +click` on the import - at least in Windows - and inspect the full module path for the import at the top of the file. Alternatively, in code this should also work: `import datetime; print(datetime.__file__)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The reason is. My python plugin had an issue. I had to upgrade it to the latest intelli idea version, to be compatible.

Hope it will save someone's time once googled for this issue.

--

yet.. is not nessesary the answer. how do I know that choosing the python SDK in my env actually  uses my venv dependencies - from venv and not.

I did remove all from venv. And Idea still resolves `datetime`. (it is getting from global dependencies)

So please **do not consider it as final answer**.. not yet.

It did work out though If I remove all other global deps and re-setup my venv env.

Seems, IntellyJ Idea is too intelegent - resolving with everything it could find - from venv and not.